# Android SQLite - second update always return 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been working with SQLite Android and I'm having error whenever I try to update table at the second time and I have no idea what's wrong with my code. The first update works fine.

Anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is the function I use to update table:

```
public boolean updateEvents(int id, boolean shown){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(EVENTS_COLUMN_SHOWN, shown);

    int result = db.update(EVENTS_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, EVENTS_COLUMN_ID_EVENTS + " = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    Log.d(DBHelper.class.getSimpleName(),"update result: "+result);
    return result==1;
}
```

I call that function after finishing the doInBackground() in AsyncTask class.
This is the class that calls that update function:

```
private class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Events>{
        private DBHelper dbHelper;
        @Override
        protected Events doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                if(new Connection().GetEvents() && Settings.events.size()>0){
                    dbHelper = new DBHelper(FirstActivity.this);
                    for(int i=0; i<Settings.events.size(); i++){
                        dbHelper.recordEvents(Settings.events.get(i),dbHelper.isEventsShown(Settings.events.get(i).id_event));
                    }
                    for(int a=0; a<Settings.events.size(); a++){
                        boolean shown = dbHelper.isEventsShown(Settings.events.get(a).id_event);
                        Log.d(FirstActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"shown "+a+": "+shown);
                        if(Settings.events.get(a).isEnabled() && Settings.events.get(a).isEventValid() && !shown){
                            return Settings.events.get(a);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Events events) {
            if(events!=null){
                dbHelper.updateEvents(events.id_event, true);
                showPopUp(events);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(events);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what and how your return works in updateEvents?

Comment: Have you checked if the events.id_event is same for the first and second update ?

Comment: @Thealon it works if db.update returns 1 and my events table with the specified event_id updated. It works in the first update, it returns 1 and my table updated. but the second update it fails, my data doesn't change.

Comment: Have you checked if the valud of events.id_event exists in the table for the second upate?

Comment: @dora yes. as seen in that code, I have some events. First I record (insert) all events to database. then I check if each event had shown before, if not it will return that event to the onPostExecute and update the "shown_column" to "true". and do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood what you are trying to achieve but i gave it a try.Try the below code and let me know.

```
private class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<Events>>{
private DBHelper dbHelper;
@Override
protected Events doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    ArrayList<Events> pendingEvents = new ArrayList<Events>();
    try{
        if(new Connection().GetEvents() && Settings.events.size()>0){
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(FirstActivity.this);
            for(int i=0; i<Settings.events.size(); i++){
                dbHelper.recordEvents(Settings.events.get(i),dbHelper.isEventsShown(Settings.events.get(i).id_event));
            }
            for(int a=0; a<Settings.events.size(); a++){
                boolean shown = dbHelper.isEventsShown(Settings.events.get(a).id_event);
                Log.d(FirstActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"shown "+a+": "+shown);
                if(Settings.events.get(a).isEnabled() && Settings.events.get(a).isEventValid() && !shown){
                    pendingEvents.add(Settings.events.get(a));
                   // return Settings.events.get(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pendingEvents;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Events> events) {
    if(events!=null){
        for(Events events1:events){
        dbHelper.updateEvents(events1.id_event, true);
        }
        showPopUp(events);
    }
    super.onPostExecute(events);
}
}
```

The problem (if i understood correctly) is that, you are returning doInBackground method as soon as you found one event. That is why i have put all such events in a list and returned if it after iterating it the full list of Settings.events.